# .bib file causes build crash, url error

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, urls

I have this code in my .bib file:

```
@misc{akcelerometry,
author = {Prof. Ing. Miroslav Husák, CSc.},
title = "Akcelerometry {[online]}",
url = {http://www.micro.feld.cvut.cz/home/X34SES/prednasky/08%20Akcelerometry.pdf},
type = {web page},
month = november,
year = {{2013}},
note = "[cit. 2014-03-08]"
}
```

It crashes but when i change url for example to `https://tex.stackexchange.com/` it works good.

EDIT:

bibliography style: http://pastebin.com/9KGLbuCB csn690.bst

latex code:

```
\bibliographystyle{csn690}
\bibliography{mybibliographyfile}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Which bibliography style do you use?

Comment: I have my own csn690.bst

Comment: A link to the bib style and a minimal example of LaTeX code are necessary.

Comment: check my edit I've done

Comment: Try escaping the % character: `url = {http://www.micro.feld.cvut.cz/home/X34SES/prednasky/08\%20Akcelerometry.pdf}`

Comment: It works. Write answer which I could flag as solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cause of the problem is the `%` character -- which has a "special" meaning in TeX -- in the field

```
url = {http://www.micro.feld.cvut.cz/home/X34SES/prednasky/08%20Akcelerometry.pdf},
```

"Escaping" the `%` symbol, i.e., writing it as `\%`, might at first blush seem to provide a fix. However, it introduces a new problem: A backslash character is now printed in the URL string, which makes it almost certain that your readers will be unable to find the publication online.

Rather than "escape" the `%` symbol, you should encase the entire URL string in the instruction `\url`, i.e., write the field as

```
url = "\url{http://www.micro.feld.cvut.cz/home/X34SES/prednasky/08%20Akcelerometry.pdf}",
```

The command `\url` not only typesets its argument in a monospaced ("typewriter") font but, importantly, also suspends any TeX-special meanings of characters such as `&`, `^`, `%`, `$`, `#`, and `~`.

You will need to load either the `url` or the `hyperref` package in the preamble of your document to activate the command `\url`.

Comment: Thanks, that provides me with a solution for a situation that I so far have simply accepted for my own work!

Answer (score 0):

The url command suggested by Mico did not work for me (with the url package).  It resulted in my bibliography appearing with "\url{my_url_here}" (i.e. the command rewritten verbatim), instead of just "my_url_here".

I was using the IEEEtran.bst bib style, with the follow LaTeX code:

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,Metrics}
```

As an alternative solution, this worked for me; just use quotes in the .bib entry:

```
url = "my_url_here",
```

Comment: For this answer to be meaningful I think you need to compare your situation to that of the original poster and to that which Mico posited.  What bib style, etc?

Comment: Good point, thanks.  I was using the IEEEtran.bst bib style.

Latex code:

    \bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
    \bibliography{IEEEabrv,MyBiblio}

Answer (score -2):

Escaping the `%` character:

```
url = {http://www.micro.feld.cvut.cz/home/X34SES/prednasky/08\%20Akcelerometry.pdf}
```

will help!

Comment: It will also print a backslash character in the URL string, presumably rendering it invalid.